# Finding Out The Type of Xaxis Excel Uses

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code snipet to find out what kind of axis Excel uses but I receive the error, parameter not valid at

If .CategoryType = xlTimeScale

I have tried the immediate window to get the value but receive the same error. CategoryType is read/write according to MSFT. I can set the parameter but can't read it.

```
        For Each cChart In Charts
        sChartName = cChart.Name
        With cChart.Axes(xlValue)
            If sChartName <> "chtGainLoss" Then
                .MinimumScale = sngY1Min
                .MaximumScale = sngY1Max
                .MajorUnit = sngMajor1
                .MinorUnit = sngMinor1
            Else
                .MinimumScale = sngY2Min
                .MaximumScale = sngY2Max
                .MajorUnit = sngMajor2
                .MinorUnit = sngMinor2
            End If
        End With
        With cChart.Axes(xlCategory)
            If .CategoryType = xlTimeScale Then
                .MinimumScale = lXMin
                .MaximumScale = lXMax
            End If
        End With
        If cChart.Axes.Count = 3 Then
            With cChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
                .MinimumScale = sngY2Min
                .MaximumScale = sngY2Max
                .MajorUnit = sngMajor2
                .MinorUnit = sngMinor2
            End With
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error. What type of chart are you working with?

Comment: I believe that if your chart type does not support a date axis, you will get that message. Date axes are available on stock charts, line charts, column charts, bar charts, and area charts

Comment: @Ricardo I'm using a line chart and a scatter plot.  Both result in the same error. 'Parameter Invalid'. I am really only trying to read .CategoryType which has 3 possible values.

Comment: @ Ron. This happens with a line chart too. .CategoryType only should result in 3 possible values 'Auto' Date 'Text'